# Let $g(z)=e^{f(\frac{1}{z})}$ then $Res_{0}g=f'(0)e^{f(0)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Given a holomorphic function $f$ let $g(z)=e^{f(\frac{1}{z})}$.  Prove that $Res_{0}g=f'(0)e^{f(0)}$.

edit:
I undestand by the answer how do I get to:
$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}z^{2}e^{f(\frac{1}{z})}=f'(1/z)$
but from there I'm stuck.

Comment: Where is $f$ holomorphic?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

1. Write $$\mathrm{Res}_0(g) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z| = 1} e^{f(1/z)}\,dz  $$ where the integral is counterclockwise.
2. Change coordinates by setting $w = 1/z$ to see $$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|w| = 1} \frac{e^{f(w)}}{w^2}\,dw$$

where again the integral is counterclockwise.

3. By Cauchy's integral theorem what is this equal to?

Comment: The second integral will have negative sign in the integrand.

Comment: Nitin check the orientation of your integral if you still have a negative sign.  Hash man, no I used the definition of the residue.

Comment: I've reached the formula in the question, I do understand it equals to the derivative, can't understand how to transfer $e^f(0)$.

Comment: @hashman use the chain rule.

Comment: @MarcusM I'll get this $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}z^{2}e^{f(\frac{1}{z})}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}(e^{f(\frac{1}{z})})'=f'(1/z)$. do I know that $\oint f'=f$?

Comment: The integral in question is $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|w| = 1} \frac{e^{f(w)}}{w^2}\,dw = \frac{d}{dw} e^{f(w)} \big|_{w = 0}$$

Comment: sorry, have you missed dividing by w on the right side?

Comment: @hashman, I have not.

Answer (score 0):

To continuous Marcus M's answer, use the Cauchy integral formula for antiderivatives of $f(\omega)$:

$$\int_{|\omega|=1}\frac{f(\omega)}{(\xi-\omega)^{n+1}}d\omega=\frac{2\pi i}{n!}f^{(n)}(\xi)$$